# Terminate script after 30 seconds of no user input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to create a simple Bash script that terminates after 10 seconds of waiting for user input. If the user inputs something, the timer is reset and the 10 second rule applies again. I'm using trap to ensure that the only two ways my program can exit are:

1. I enter "stop"
2. User does not input for 10 seconds

I tried using something like:

```
{
sleep 10s
kill $$
} &
```

But after pressing Ctrl-C, it doesn't stop the program after 10s. It goes on indefinitely.

Comment: If you trap `SIGINT`, the script will never exit via ctrl+c. That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Note that in the example you deleted you have a quoting issue with `won't` (to avoid this, you can make a trap function and call that from the trap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the time out option for `read`. But note this doesn't reset when a user hits a key, only when they press enter to finish their input.

```
read -t 10 userinput || exit 1
```

If you're using `set -e`, you can ommit `|| exit 1`.

`read` can fail for other reasons, so you can test for a timeout specifically. Timeout error code is anything greater than 128.

```
read -t 10 userinput || { (($?>128)) && exit 1; }
```

Or

```
if ! read -t 10 userinput && (($? > 128)); then
    echo 'you timed out' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

If `read` fails, you probably want to exit anyway. But testing for a timeout error code allows you to print a relevant error message.

Comment: This is great. It works when I input any text, and resets the timer. However, when I press Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-C, I also want it to reset the timer. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: It might be possible, but I can't think of how off the top of my head. At least not without a lot of messing around. You would need to end `read` prematurely, then start it again, and do that (or at least trigger it) from a trap. A better approach might be to restart `read` if a string like `time` is entered instead. If it's important, I suggest asking a new question, where you show your code, and provide more context about what you're trying to acheive overall.

Answer (score 0):

read has a parameter for timeout, you can use:

```
read -t 30 answer
```

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX TTY line discipline provides such a feature: a configurable timer that is reset whenever input arrives, and which terminates the `read()` operation when it expires. This timer is typically useful for generating larger reads when the TTY is in raw mode, like from a serial line.

There are a few tricky things in this proof-of-concept solution. It handles the requirement that Ctrl-Z suspend works during the read, and resets the timer:

```
#!/bin/sh

# save the TTY settings, to restore later
# this should ideally be done in an exit/interrupt trap.
saved_tty=$(stty -g)

# initialize some variables
resumed=            # flag indicating Ctrl-Z resume
biginput=           # total input collected
littleinput=        # input from one read operation

# function to set a special TTY mode, and set the resumed flag
set_tty_mode()
{
  # turn of canonical mode; set up 10 second timer (100 x 0.1s)
  # min 0 means read a minimum of 0 bytes, allowing timer to work

  stty -icanon min 0 time 100 

  # setting this flag plays a role when this function is called
  # as the SIGCONT interrupt handler.
  resumed=y
}

# switch to above TTY mode
set_tty_mode

# when the SIGCONT signal goes off, indicating we resumed from Ctrl-Z
# suspend, call set_tty_mode. This is because when we are suspended,
# the shell, e.g. Bash, messes with the TTY settings.
trap set_tty_mode CONT

# no we loop, reading into the littleinput variable.
while true ; do
  resumed=                          # clear the flag
  read littleinput                  # read input
  biginput="$biginput$littleinput"  # accumulate
  [ $resumed ] || break             # terminate loop, unless SIGCONT happened
done

printf "read: [%s]\n" "$biginput"

stty $saved_tty
```